# My gdb disassemble doesnt display properly

Tags: macos, ubuntu, gdb, disassembly

[image]

I am using GDB to analyze a binary file using layout asm and layout regs.
After I typed layout asm and layout regs, it displays properly.
However after i typed a few step commands, the screen doesnt display properly.
I am running ubuntu on my macAir.

Comment: I solved this using gdb -tui binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after i typed a few step commands, the screen doesnt display properly

Do a `refresh` command or type `Control-L`

Comment: Ya this works! But I have to retype refresh every time... still thanks!